# Отключить вывод информации

Tags: apache, php

В браузер почему-то начала выводиться следующая информация:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 09:21:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 08:39:53 GMT
ETag: "b21984-ed9-505219c104f54"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3801
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Как избавиться от ее вывода?

В начале скрипта прописал:

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
@error_reporting( 0 );
```

в .htaccess прописал:

```
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag display_startup_errors off
```

Не помогает...

Comment: А причем тут экранирование ошибок, и информация ? :)

Comment: @arashvg, 

1. Я правильно понимаю, что вышеописанный вывод вы видите не в консоли браузера, а там, где должне быть переданный документ?
2. Если ответ на 1 - да, то где находится сервер и какое оборудование может фильтровать запросы между ним и вами? Такое возможно, если кто-то добавляет свои заголовки ответа и отбивает их довйным переводом строки.

Comment: @Etki, #2, как это так: кто-то может добавлять свои заголовки? Не встречал такой магии просто.

Comment: @kohana, любой прокси, я думаю, даже над тем же nginx на уровне конфигов можно поиздеваться, чтобы он такое делал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array ( 
 [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 [1] => Server: nginx/1.2.1 
 [2] => Date: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 10:53:20 GMT 
 [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
 [4] => Content-Length: 2906 
 [5] => Connection: close 
 [6] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14 
 [7] => Vary: Accept-Encoding 
)
```

Такой ответ от сервера вызывает функция

```
get_headers()
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-headers.php

Comment: Такой функции нету ни в одном файле.

Comment: @arashvg, ну, сам по себе он же не будет возвращать заголовки :)

Вот еще список функций, которые возвращают заголовки

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.apache.php